# .NET MVC Masking Password textboxes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I was under the impression that using an annotation like this:

```
<Required()>
<DisplayName("Choose a Password:")>
<ValidatePasswordLength()>
<DataType(DataType.Password)>
Public Property Password As String
```

Would create a masked field when used in the view:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Password) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Password) %>
```

However this is rendered without the type="password"

What is the "DataType.Password" used for if not this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using `Html.TextBoxFor` which always outputs an `<input type="text">` tag in the resulting HTML.
If you want the DataType.Password annotation to be automatically honored you should use `Html.EditorFor` instead.
You can read more about editor templates and how to customize them here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: By the same token does that apply for fields that are marked as DataType.EmailAddress ?

Comment: The DisplayFor method has a default template for EmailAddress. However there is no default editor for emails that EditorFor could use. It will just use a plain text box. You could write a custom editor template, however.

Answer (score 26):

`TextBoxFor` overrides your annotation because it indicates a clear text input. As marcind mentioned, `EditorFor` honors the annotation or you could use `PasswordFor` for that field.